# Drop Down Menu Similar to xenForo?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I create a dropdown menu similar to xenforo, which will automatically close after 2 seconds?
I've tried searching but unfortunately couldn't find any proper solution.

But I don't know how to and what code to put to achieve like; 1. The drop down menu open after 2 seconds if the mouse cursor hovers over the main menu link for 2 seconds. 2. The drop down closes if the mouse cursor is away from the drop down for 2 seconds.

Thanks!

Here is Jsfiddle;

Comment: Please share the jsfiddle link

Comment: JS fidlle is not showing above, here is its link: http://jsfiddle.net/NgVwU/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#sub-menu li").hide(); // Hide in order to fadeIn to work
    $("#main-menu ul").hover(
        function(){
            $("#sub-menu li").fadeIn(slow);
        },
        function(){
            $("#sub-menu li").fadeOut(slow);
        });
});
```

Comment: Its actually the same as posted by Swaroop, I just added ul and li

You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery to use this functionality. Instead of waiting for 2 seconds you can use fade out slow so that users can know something will happen.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#sub-menu").hide(); // Hide in order to fadeIn to work
    $("#main-menu").hover(
        function(){
            $("#sub-menu").fadeIn(slow);
        },
        function(){
            $("#sub-menu").fadeOut(slow);
        });
});
```

Comment: Please see the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/NgVwU/ , I used a class for <ul> but not for its <li> s

Comment: Can anyone please reply?
Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.dd_menu {
background: none;
padding: 0px;
margin:0;
list-style-type:none;
height:10px;
border: none;
font-size: 11px;
font-family: "Candarab";
}

.dd_menu li {
background: none;
float: left !important;
height:20px;
margin-left: 1px;
margin-top: 4px;
}

.dd_menu li a {
padding: 15px 5px;
display:inline;
color:#000;
text-decoration:none;
font:11px arial, verdana, sans-serif;
}

.dd_menu li:hover a {
text-decoration:none;
padding: 15px 5px;
}

.dd_menu ul {
position:absolute;
left:-9999px;
top:9px;
list-style-type:none;
text-decoration: none;
float: left !important;
}

.dd_menu li:hover {
position:relative;
background:#176093;
text-decoration: none;
z-index: 1000;
}

.dd_menu li:hover ul {
left:0px;
top:20px;
background:lavender;
padding: 3px 3px;
border:1px solid grey;
width:160px;
text-decoration: none;
}

.dd_menu li:hover ul li {
height:18px;
border:none;
}

.dd_menu li:hover ul li a {
height:18px;
padding:0px;
display:block;
font-size:11px;
width:158px;
line-height:18px;
text-indent:5px;
color:#444;
background-color:lavender;
text-decoration:none;
border:1px solid transparent;
}

.dd_menu li:hover ul li a:hover {
height:18px;
background:silver;
color:#000;
float: left;
border:solid 1px #444;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<ul class="dd_menu">
    <li><a href="#">Main Menu <span class="smallesttext">&#x25BC;</span></a>
  <ul>
    <div align="left">
        <li><a href="#">Drop Down Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Drop Down Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Drop Down Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Drop Down Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Drop Down Link</a></li>
    </div>
  </ul>
</li>
</ul>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".dd_menu li a").hover(
        function(){
            $(".dd_menu li ul div li a").hide().fadeIn('slow');
        },
        function(){
        });
    $("ul div li").hover(
        function(){
            $(".dd_menu li ul div li a").show();
        },
        function(){
            ;
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Try this. Similarly add what you want on mouse out. If it helped think about accepting the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your input Swaroop, the issue is when the mouse cursor moves over the drop down links its shows abrupt fading effect. Here is jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZyAm3/

I'm jscript noob :(

Comment: Why I accept it even it doesn't work to the way I want? :/ However I do not forget to thanks you or any one who tries to help.

Comment: Accept the answer. Il reply

Comment: Can you please now reply Swaroop?

Comment: I did reply. Didnt you get it>

Comment: Nope, did you posted here or any where else?

Comment: Also if you please edit this jsfiddle properly it would be easy for me to get the code.: http://jsfiddle.net/ZyAm3/

Thanks!

Comment: I think something is wrong as well. See this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZyAm3/1/

Its updated version of the previous one. Please see the behaviour of the menus. The dropdown links of one menu is fine but the other dropdown links are cluttered one to other.

Please help to resolve this too.

Comment: I'm waiting for your reply! :(